# What if DBCursor is not closed?

Tags: java, mongodb

What happens if `DBCursor` *is not* closed after iterating over all items. I do understand that `DBCursor` should be closed. I wonder what happens if it is not.

It looks like it does not cause any memory leak. The documentation says cursor will be closed either *if client has exhausted the cursor* or by timeout. My understanding is that the cursor will be closed after iterating over all items. Does it make sense ?

Comment: It may not cause a memory leak but it can cause resource leaks quite quickly if you have a lot of them. Take it this way: when you go out for a walk, do you leave your house open?

Answer (score 2):

The server closes the cursor after 10 minutes of inactivity. See [Closure of inactive cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#closure-of-inactive-cursors)

Comment: Thank you for the link. They say it will be closed if `client has exhausted the cursor`.

Comment: @Michael The cursor is exhausted when all of the results return. Sof if you fetch all the results the cursor will close. If you do not fetch all the results, after a period of time of inactivity (typically 10mins) the open cursors will be closed by the server.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. That's how I understand it too.